# Naming conventions of predictor variables

Tags: r

Specific Examples:

```
log1 <- glm(Outcome ~ Predictor1 + Predictor2, family = binomial(link="logit"),
             data=data)

log2 <- glm(data$Outcome ~ data$Predictor1 + data$Predictor2, 
       family = binomial(link="logit"))
```

These will produce the same models and their summaries will be identical.

Then why when using these models to predict an outcome from test data, do the values differ?

Example:

```
predict(log1,type = "response", newdata = test_dat) == 
predict(log2,type = "response", newdata = test_dat) = "FALSE"
```

I am not as familiar with R as I would like, but I can't seem to explain the differences. Help?

Comment: You are missing two `"`, one after each `logit`. If you add them do you get the result you want?

Comment: The missing " was a mistake in typing up this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two objects use `identical(log1, log2)` ; however, the problem is that the names are part of the objects so if the names are different then the objects cannot be identical even if all the numbers underlying them are the same.

For example, note how `Time` and `BOD$Time` are part of `fm1` and `fm2`:

```
fm1 <- lm(demand ~ Time, BOD)
fm2 <- lm(BOD$demand ~ BOD$Time)

fm1[[1]]
## (Intercept)        Time 
##    8.521429    1.721429 

fm2[[1]]
## (Intercept)    BOD$Time 
##    8.521429    1.721429
```

Comment: This was the answer. Thank you for explaining.

Comment: if this was the answer, you're encouraged (in addition to or even instead of commenting) to click on the check-mark to accept it.